# How to return a constant collection

Tags: java

Is there a way in java to return a reference to a class collection where I cant change it nor  change data of its elements?

So if I have a map `Map<Integer, Set<String>>` no body could get reference to the set value and add elements to it?

Comment: you can clone it before handing to someone, so even if he changes it it will not grief your program

Comment: but if it really large this would be too much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to guarantee that all the objects *inside* a `Map`can't be modified, even if the `Map` itself is unmodifiable, would be to make the objects themselves *immutable*.

The `unmodifiableMap()` method guarantees that the `Map` can not be modified, but it makes no guarantees at all regarding the *objects* it contains. Take a look at [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29) to have an idea of how you can make an object immutable. For a concrete example, see how the `String` class works: you can't modify the characters inside a string, and all the methods that could change the string (for instance: `toUpperCase()`) really return a *new* string. That's the behavior you want for the objects inside your `Map`.

Given that the map in the question contains `Set<String>` as its values, then using `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` on the sets *before* adding them to the map will make them immutable, because `String`, as stated above, is already immutable.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Collections.unmodifiableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29) to get a view of a map that cannot be modified.

There is a different method for each type of collection:

- `unmodifiableCollection` returns an unmodifiable view of a generic Collection
- `unmodifiableSet` returns an unmodifiable view of a Set
- `unmodifiableList` returns an unmodifiable view of a List
- `unmodifiableSortedSet` returns an unmodifiable view of a SortedSet
- `unmodifiableSortedMap` returns an unmodifiable view of a SortedMap

If the items are collections themselves you can write a recursive method to construct a new collection that holds unmodifiable views of the original items.

In general, if the items you store in a collection can themselves be modified, nothing stops you from doing that, short of making defensive copies.

Comment: I used that and it dont work, I could get a reference to one of the values in the map and change its data.

Comment: That is a totally different question! A collection of Unmodifiable objects is not at all the same as an Unmodifiable collection. The answer to this question is no.

Comment: @Doggynub apart from decorating the `Map` as unmodifiable, you should also decorate the `Set`s elements as unmodifiable as well. If you want to do it with your own classes, you must make sure your classes are immutable as well.

Comment: yes my object are immutable but they are contained in collection so how about that recursive function?

Comment: Seeing that you have only one level of nested collections (`Map<Integer,Set<String>>`) you don't really need a recursive function. Just construct a new map and iterate over the keys and values of the existing one, doing `newMap.put(key, Collections.unmodifiableSet(value))` for each pair.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easiest to accomplish your goal by mediating access to the outer collection (The `Map`) via your own provided method(s). You could then return the appropriate `Set` object after passing it through `Collections.unmodifiableSet()`.

Since `String` is immutable, there's really nothing left for the callers to change after that.

Short of that, you'd have to construct a new `Map` populated with sets all passed through `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` and then pass that through `Collections.unmodifiableMap()`. But, that may or may not be a good idea depending how large your collection is.

Comment: isn't there a way I could have that set immutable too without copying new stuff?

Comment: this would only make copy of the map elements not the set ones right? the set would just be returned from immutable view in the new map?

Comment: Correct, it's a shallow copy (which is really the reason you want them to be immutable). I guess since the `Map` is copied, there's no real need afterward to make it unmodifiable. As far as a way to achieve your goal directly... I don't know of any builtin way. I think you'd need to do something like roll your own unmodifiable map implementation that passed the returned values through `unmodifiableSet()`.

Answer (score 1):

Map:

```
Map<Integer, String> myMap =
            Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<Integer, String>() {
        {
            put(1, "value1");
            put(2, "value2");
            put(3, "value3");
        }
    });
```

List:

```
List<String> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("value1");
            add("value2");
            add("value3");
        }
    });
```

Set:

```
Set<String> list = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>() {
        {
            add("value1");
            add("value2");
            add("value3");
        }
    });
```